# Is there a way to use float values in my stat percentage module?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a stat module that a user will input a value and the value will then dynamically fill a circular progress bar. I have it working with integers values but when I use a decimal value such as 99.9 the increment won't stop. I have tried using parseInt but it still won't work. Any recommendations on how to fix?

```js
const statContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".stat-container");
const options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: "-150px"
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    }

    let container = entry.target;

    let circularProgress = container.querySelector(".circular-progress"),
      progressValue = container.querySelector(".progress-value");

    let progressValueMax = progressValue.setAttribute("data-max", progressValue.innerText);

    let progressStartValue = 0,
      // progressEndValue = progressValue.dataset.max,
      progressEndValue = (parseFloat(progressValue.innerText)),
      speed = 1;

    console.log(progressEndValue);

    let progress = setInterval(() => {
      progressStartValue++;

      progressValue.textContent = `${progressStartValue}`;
      circularProgress.style.background = `conic-gradient(#099bf0, #7cbf3d,#00b3cf, #1f58f2, #5618d4 ${progressStartValue * 3.6}deg, #EAEAEC 0deg)`;

      if (progressStartValue == progressEndValue) {
        clearInterval(progress);
      }
    }, speed);

    observer.unobserve(entry.target);
  })
}, options);

statContainer.forEach(stat => {
  observer.observe(stat);
});
```

```css
/* Start of Stat Styling */
.stat-container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

/* Controls Color of the Ring */
.circular-progress {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(#5618d4, #1f58f2, #099bf0, #00b3cf, #7cbf3d 0deg, #EAEAEC 0deg);
}

/* Controls Color Inside of the Ring */
.circular-progress::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.progress-value {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(360deg, #5618D4, #1F58F2, #099BF0);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3.875rem;
  line-height: 3.875rem;
}
.progress-value:after {
  content: "%";
}
.text {
  color: #060F42;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.125rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.24px;
  max-width: 582px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* End of Stat Styling */
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value">99.9</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value">70</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value">99</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe use `progressStartValue >= progressEndValue` instead of `progressStartValue == progressEndValue`?

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried that as well but the value will round up or down instead of keeping the decimal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the end value is being rounded after changing from `==` to `>=` then manually set the value to the desired end after canceling the interval.

```js
let progress = setInterval(() => {
  progressStartValue++;

  if (progressStartValue >= progressEndValue) {
    clearInterval(progress);
    progressStartValue = progressEndValue; // Set to desired end
  }
      
  // Update after the check...
  progressValue.textContent = progressStartValue;
  circularProgress.style.background = computeGradientForPercentage(progressStartValue);
}, speed);
```

### Fixed snippet

```js
const statContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".stat-container");
const options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: "-150px"
};

// The percentage should be between [0, 100]
function computeGradientForPercentage(percentage) {
  return `conic-gradient(#099bf0, #7cbf3d,#00b3cf, #1f58f2, #5618d4 ${percentage * 3.6}deg, #EAEAEC 0deg)`;
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    }

    let container = entry.target;

    let circularProgress = container.querySelector(".circular-progress"),
      progressValue = container.querySelector(".progress-value");

    let progressValueMax = progressValue.setAttribute("data-max", progressValue.innerText);

    let progressStartValue = 0,
      // progressEndValue = progressValue.dataset.max,
      progressEndValue = (parseFloat(progressValue.innerText)),
      speed = 1;

    //console.log(progressEndValue);

    let progress = setInterval(() => {
      progressStartValue++;

      if (progressStartValue >= progressEndValue) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        progressStartValue = progressEndValue;
      }
      
      // Update after the check...
      progressValue.textContent = progressStartValue;
      circularProgress.style.background = computeGradientForPercentage(progressStartValue);
    }, speed);

    observer.unobserve(entry.target);
  })
}, options);

statContainer.forEach(stat => {
  observer.observe(stat);
});
```

```css
/* Start of Stat Styling */
.stat-container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

/* Controls Color of the Ring */
.circular-progress {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(#5618d4, #1f58f2, #099bf0, #00b3cf, #7cbf3d 0deg, #EAEAEC 0deg);
}

/* Controls Color Inside of the Ring */
.circular-progress::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.progress-value {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(360deg, #5618D4, #1F58F2, #099BF0);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3.875rem;
  line-height: 3.875rem;
}
.progress-value:after {
  content: "%";
}
.text {
  color: #060F42;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.125rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.24px;
  max-width: 582px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* End of Stat Styling */
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value">99.9</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value">70</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value">99</span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You are never showing floating-point values while the loop is running. You could display a fixed number instead. Also, since your `speed` is `1`, the number will never show a decimal value.

```js
progressValue.textContent = progressStartValue.toFixed(1); // Show 1 decmal
```

### Using data attributes

Here is an alternate example that uses data attributes:

```js
const statContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".stat-container");
const options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: "-150px"
};

// The percentage should be between [0, 100]
function computeGradientForPercentage(percentage) {
  return `conic-gradient(#099bf0, #7cbf3d,#00b3cf, #1f58f2, #5618d4 ${percentage * 3.6}deg, #EAEAEC 0deg)`;
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      return;
    }
    const
      container = entry.target,
      circularProgress = container.querySelector('.circular-progress'),
      progressValue = circularProgress.querySelector('.progress-value'),
      progressValueMin = 0,
      progressValueMax = +(progressValue.dataset.max ?? '100'),
      precision = Math.abs(Math.log10(+(progressValue.dataset.step ?? '1'))),
      speed = 1;
    let currentValue = progressValueMin;
    progressValue.textContent = currentValue;
    let progress = setInterval(() => {
      currentValue++;
      if (currentValue >= progressValueMax) {
        clearInterval(progress);
        progress = null;
        currentValue = progressValueMax;
      }
      // Update after the check
      progressValue.textContent = currentValue.toFixed(precision);
      circularProgress.style.background = computeGradientForPercentage(currentValue);
    }, speed);
    observer.unobserve(entry.target);
  })
}, options);

statContainer.forEach(observer.observe);
```

```css
/* Start of Stat Styling */
.stat-container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 30px;
}

/* Controls Color of the Ring */
.circular-progress {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(#5618d4, #1f58f2, #099bf0, #00b3cf, #7cbf3d 0deg, #EAEAEC 0deg);
}

/* Controls Color Inside of the Ring */
.circular-progress::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.progress-value {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(360deg, #5618D4, #1F58F2, #099BF0);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3.875rem;
  line-height: 3.875rem;
}
.progress-value:after {
  content: "%";
}
.text {
  color: #060F42;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2.125rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.24px;
  max-width: 582px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* End of Stat Styling */
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value" data-max="99.9" data-step="0.1"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value" data-max="70"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="stat-container">
    <div class="circular-progress">
      <span class="progress-value" data-max="99"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mr Polywhirl! This helps a lot! Thank you. Sorry but another question. When the value is 99.5 the conic gradient is still at 360deg. Is there a way for it to represent the conic gradient as 99.5% instead of it filling up 100%?

Comment: @rnkwill I moved some of the logic around. You should perform the bounds checking first, then update the display. I updated all the code snippets above.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I have been working on this for  weeks now.

Comment: polywhirl Now one last question if it isn't too much work. I've been looking into LERP but that has been going over my head. Is there a way for all the animations to reach the final value at the same time? so like 50% and 99% would be the same to fill up

Comment: @rnkwill LERP is short for "linear interpolation". You are setting the value between two points with a percentage from [0, 1]. If you want them to finish at the same time, your speed will have to be proportional to the distance between the start and end e.g. `speed = 1 / (end - start)`

Comment: I see so in my care it would be speed = 1 / (progressEndValue - progressStartValue); ?

Comment: @rnkwill be careful, in your example you modify `progressStartValue`. You will need the original start value, or capture the speed before you mutate the variable.

Comment: Ah okay so then I am setting the speed again in the setInterval after the check?

Comment: @rnkwill no, you can compute the speed once. As long as you know the start and end values, you can obtain the duration. The inverse duration multiplies by some factor should be computed before the interval/animation.

Comment: I guess after some messing around I am confused again.. progressStartValue = 0 initially but then increments in the set interval to equal the same value as progressEndValue? Maybe I am not understanding correctly.